# Repeat a listbox that opens files

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, timer, repeat

Hello I want my listbox playlist to repeat after last file is played.
How do I reset the index so it repeats to the start of the listbox?
Shownextimage handles the media one by one to show on the mediaelement. The DispatcherTimer shows Images 20 seconds and then continues.

This is what I got.

```
    Dictionary<string, string> Listbox1Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public static List<string> images = new List<string> { ".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG" }; // Bildtyper som stöds
    public static List<string> movies = new List<string> { ".WMV", ".WAV", ".SWF", ".MP4", ".MPG", ".AVI" };
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    DispatcherTimer NextImageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    int x = 20;
    private int currentSongIndex = -1;
    private void ShowNextImage()
    {
        if (currentSongIndex == -1)
        {
            currentSongIndex = Listbox1.SelectedIndex;
        }
        currentSongIndex++;

        var selected = Listbox1.Items[currentSongIndex];
        string s = selected.ToString();
        if (Listbox1Dict.ContainsKey(s))
        {

            if (images.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {

                if (currentSongIndex < Listbox1.Items.Count)
                {
                    mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(Listbox1Dict[s]);

                }
            }
            else if (movies.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).ToUpperInvariant()))
            {
                if (currentSongIndex < Listbox1.Items.Count)
                {
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                    mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(Listbox1Dict[s]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Timers:

```
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ShowNextImage();
    }
    private void dispatch()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=Index, Path=Value}">
        <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Slider x:Name="Index" Minimum="0" Maximum="2" Value="2" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In this sample the selected index of the listbox is bound to the value of the slider. The slider should be replaced by an indexproperty in your ViewModel that notifies when changed. Your index prop should increment after finishing playing a song and set to 0 if the song was the last. I think this should be handled in your vm.

Comment: Hej Johan!
Tack för svar. Hur kopplar jag slider till mitt mediaelement?

Hello Johan, thanks for answer. How do I connect Slider with Mediaelement?

Comment: maybe I misread your question, is the listbox "inside" the mediaelement?

Comment: Is there anyway you can do it in my code that I provided?

IF playlist ended
reset Indexvalue to 1
Or something like that

Comment: the idea with the slider was just to illustrate how to bind SelectedIndex of the listbox. I don't think you want the slider at all and expose a property Index in your viewmodel and bind the listbox SelectedIndex to that.

Comment: So I bind Mediaelement with the listbox?
The listbox gets all items from a string that I get from a folderdialog.

Comment: I'd say you want to bind the listbox ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of mediaelements and the SelectedIndex to a corresponding property.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to. Can you make a code for me ?

Comment: I don't have the time, search for a tutorial on MVVM, that should cover it. Good luck.